# KSC Reports via Email/System output

Tags: opennms

I have a KSC report that i run once a month that gives me the previous months usages on specific firewall interfaces i am interested in.

Is there any way to get this report via email in a PDF for example? Or Alternatively get the output via a script onto the file system?

Thanks

Joe.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment.

There is some work ongoing to make KSC reports available via Grafana, which has a "snapshot" feature that might meet your requirement.

Comment: I can't upvote this as im a new user but thanks for the update! I endedup witht he same answer in IRC! Cheers.